# How to insert text in a textbox on a website using Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I'm trying to insert text into the textbox of a website but I seem to be doing something incorrect because I keep getting an error in the Powershell IDE. The code I'm using is:

```
($ie.Document.DocumentElement.getElementsByClassName('web-password-input') | Select-Object -First 1).value = 'asdf'
```

The error it shows in the IDE is:

```
The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\file.ps1:53 char:5
+     ($ie.Document.DocumentElement.getElementsByClassName('web-passwor ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

I used this code earlier in the project and it worked correctly, granted this is to submit a button and not insert text.

```
$fs = $ie.Document.DocumentElement.getElementsByClassName('right-nav button button-link last') | Select-Object -first 1
$fs.click()
```

The HTML code that I'm trying to target is:

```html
<web-password-input aria-invalid="{errors.password.hasErrors}" errors="{errors.password}" input-id="password" aria-described-by="error-message1" focus="{pwdFocus}" ready="{passwordComponentReady}" classes="content-input" placeholder="new password" flow="{flow}" value="{password}" strength="{strength}" percentage="{percentage}" {password-policy}="passwordPolicy">    
    
  <input class="pwd form-textbox form-textbox-text  override error has-errors content-input" id="password" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="error-message1" type="password" placeholder="new password" autocomplete="off" can-field="{value}" errors="{errors}">
```

Any advice or pointers you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `<web-password-input` looks like a (made-up) tag name, not a class assigned to a tag. `getElementsByClassName` can't find it, because it's not a class name. [Maybe this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can help.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick, enough for me to edit the information that I needed.